# How to Send Mail Async

Tags: c#, .net, identity

I am running into an issue when trying to send an Email Async, I found out a no of post on Stackoverflow but none of them was helpful. I have following block of code

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.

        var mailMessage = new MailMessage
            ("me@example.com", message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body);

        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        var client = new SmtpClient();

        client.SendCompleted += (s, e) => client.Dispose();
        client.SendAsync(mailMessage,null);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

I got an email but getting an exception when this block of code run

```
an asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Uh? What made you think `Task.FromResult(0)` has anything to do with your call to `SendAsync()`?

Comment: Then what I suppose to do? That line of code has already been there in IdentityConfig.cs. I just plug in my Email Service above that line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`SendMailAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `SendAsync`:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.

        var mailMessage = new MailMessage
            ("me@example.com", message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body);

        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using(var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should dispose of mailMessage too.

Comment: Very useful Thank You @MarcinJuraszek

Comment: @MarkRichman i want to do some post-processing after the mail has been sent, how could i get the object to find which mail has been sent from bulk mails (say 100 mails)

Comment: @Abbas I have no idea. I haven't used .NET in 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

-Future readers, dispose the MailMessage, or as I prefer to do use the using syntax! I don't know how much memory you lose when you don't dispose it or if it can somehow be reclaimed. I am going to be sending a lot of emails to users so I don't want to find out if it will stop working over time if left alone.

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
        {
            public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
            {
                // Plug in your email service here to send an email.

                using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage("me@example.com", message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body))
                {
                    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: how could we ascertain which email has been went through and which has failed.